# Which prop. of $\mathbb{R}$ results in absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Assuma that we are in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|a_n|}$ converges. Then we can say that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ converges as follows:

For any $n$, $a_n \leq |a_n|$ so $0 \leq a_n +|a_n|  \leq 2.|a_n|$ . We can say that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|a_n|}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{2.|a_n|}$ also converges. Now by comparision test, we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n +|a_n|}$ converges $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n }$ converges.

This is the common proof that I have seen.

What is the property of $\mathbb{R}$ that leads the implication *absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence* that is not visible in those proofs?

Comment: You considered the definition of absolute-value function?

Comment: [Real Analysis In Reverse][rair], by James Propp, is an interesting read. It proves, among many other things, that this property alone is not equivalent to (Dedekind- or Cauchy-)completeness in the presence of the axioms of ordered fields. (That is, while every complete ordered field certainly satisfies "absolute convergence implies convergence", the converse is false: the field of formal Laurent series is not complete but does satisfy the property.) So completeness is *not* the property of $\mathbb{R}$ you seek.

[rair]:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4483.pdf

Comment: The article looks great, I am checking it. 
Is it the monotone sequence property that is written in the answer below, then?

Comment: The monotone sequence property is equivalent to completeness, which then implies "absolute convergence => convergence".

Comment: The completeness of the Real number system is the property that you want: Every Cauchy sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers has a limit. There are several equivalents of completeness, but completeness is a fundamental property. The least upper bound property is equivalent to completeness, as is the convergence of bounded monotone sequences.

Answer (score 2):

It is the **monotone sequence property**. Since $a_n + |a_n| \ge 0$ the partial sums $$\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n + |a_n|)$$ are nondecreasing. The fact that $a_n + |a_n| \le 2|a_n|$ means that the partial sums are bounded above by $2 \sum |a_n|$ so that the sequence of partial sums converges to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + |a_n|).$$ Now you can apply the elementary limit laws to show $\sum a_n$ converges too.

Comment: Well, does it have another name because I could not find any resource about it?

Comment: AKA monotone convergence theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem